# How to connect server to API through socket.io? I've only done client-server so far

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, express

Yesterday I started fiddling with socket.io and I were able to create a very simple app in which I could draw in 1 tab and see the line I'm drawing in the other tab in real time which was really cool. Now I wanna build on that knowledge by creating a simple app which shows the price of bitcoin in  real time which would require an API -> Socket -> Server -> Client structure. I have already figured out the Server - > Client but frankly I am not sure how am I supposed to connect the API to my server through a socket. Any ideas, tips, articles, etc on that matter would be really helpful since when I try to google it, I get results for different questions.

My www file:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

 io.on('error', console.error)

 io.on('connection', function(socket) {
     console.log('A New User Has Connected: ' + socket.id);
     socket.on('disconnect', function(){
         console.log('A User Has Disconnected')
     });
 });
```

Comment: On your server, get current price of bitcoin.  If price is different than last time you looked, then use `io.emit(...)` to send the new price to all connected clients.  Repeat every so often.

Comment: That's my problem, I don't know how to connect my server to the bitcoin API. The SSL URL is wss://api.bitfinex.com/ws but I'm not sure how to connect to it.

Comment: Then, you should make your question about exactly what problem you want help with, explain which API you're trying to use, show what code you tried, etc...  Right now, your question isn't about anything specific like that.

Comment: I've already created the socket between server-client and it's working as it should. However, I now have no clue how to connect it to bitfinex in order to get the bitcoin price data in real-time and send it to my server. There's some information on the website but it uses WebSocket and I use socket.io https://docs.bitfinex.com/docs

Comment: If the Bitcoin service uses webSocket, then you use webSocket to connect to it so you can get its data. Once you have new data, you send that over your socket.io client connections using `io.emit(...)`. You don't directly connect the two. Your server connects to the bitcoin service using whatever system it offers (it sounds like webSocket in this case). Once you are connected there, when you receive an update in the price, you then send that price over the socket.io connections. Your server works as the interconnect, but the two types of connections are not directly connected to each other.

Comment: So if bitfinex uses WebSocket, I can't use socket.io to make the connection?

Comment: Correct.  While socket.io uses webSocket under the covers, it also adds a layer on top making the two incompatible.  A webSocket server must be connected to with a plain webSocket client and a socket.io server mus be connected to with a socket.io client.  This is no big deal.  It just means you have to make a plain webSocket connection to your bitcoin service and when you get the current price over the webSocket connection, you then manually send that price to the socket.io clients.